# Bridgewater's Daily Observations

Tags: research, hedging, reference-request

Bridgewater Associates send out Daily Observations to their clients, but I haven't found many traces of these publications online. The series started some 40 years ago by Ray Dalio, and there're just few papers lying around.

Some [publications are available](https://www.bwater.com/home/research--press/daily-observations.aspx) upon registration on bwater.com:

- Formula for Economic Success - Part 2 - October 31, 2012
- Formula for Economic Success - Part 1 - October 30, 2012
- Seeing Today's Crisis from Two Worlds - June 18, 2012
- Hedge Fund Returns Dominated by Beta - May 3, 2012
- Asset Class Returns in Deleveragings - April 19, 2012
- A Beautiful Deleveraging - February 24, 2012
- Update on the Seismic Shift - January 3, 2012
- Approaching the Seismic Shift - April 25, 2011
- More Will Likely be Necessary from the Fed - July 29, 2010
- The New Decade: 2010-2019 - January 11, 2010
- A Modern Day D-Process - April 28, 2009
- Great Moves! - September 19, 2008
- An Inflection Point in Banking - April 29, 2008
- Hedge Funds Selling Beta as Alpha (An Update) - May 24, 2005
- The Biggest Mistake in Investing - August 18, 2004
- It's All Macro - May 7, 2004
- The Next Decade - January 5, 2000
- The First Day of the New...Decade, Century, or Millennium - January 4, 2000

But that's just a fraction of them. Are there more anywhere else?

Comment: You're unlikely to find them easily: http://dealbreaker.com/2009/06/bridgewater-is-sick-and-tired-of-its-pearls-of-wisdom-getting-widely-disseminated/.

Comment: Not anymore but Ray Dalio has been active in sharing his wisdom and thoughts in his various books (e.g. big debt crisis). He also shared the principles and the allocation % of the all-weather portfolio in Tony Robbin's Money: Master of the games book.